# How do I show content when Javascript isn't available, hide it when javascript is available and not flicker in either case?

Tags: javascript, html, css, progressive-enhancement, graceful-degradation

I have a simple form for shipping options and I am using javascript to auto submit the form when someone selects a new option from the drop down list.

In order to support browsers without javascript there is also a button to submit the form. This button is hidden using javascript.

However, this means my button is visible for a brief period of time and can cause a flicker as the rest of the content is reformatted.

Can anyone suggest a way of creating the button so it starts off hidden, but is made visible only if javascript is not available? eg, start out with display:none; and magically change to display:block; if and only if there is no javascript.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just put anything inside `<noscript> ... </noscript>` tags and then it will only appear if JavaScript is not enabled/available.

Comment: This would mean that everyone needs to download the HTML for each element twice. Once for the noscript-tag, and once for the hidden content to be shown by javascript.

Comment: Doh! I can't believe I didn't think of that! Since you were first to answer I've accepted your answer. Thank you all.

Comment: NOSCRIPT tags suck! They are ineffective on some mobile devices and don't work when scripts are blocked by a corporate firewall. -1

Comment: Magnar, can you put your answer back up again. I wanted to try that as well, but it seems to have gone...

Comment: JP, in that case I think the corporate firewall is certainly more to blame. I don't think web designers should *care* about bugs caused by something that's actively mangling their code as a security "feature".

Comment: Magnar - yes badly used the noscript tag can rapidly increase the page weight but used judicously can be very affective. Like any 'tool' that is used poorly the costs can outweight the benefits. I think in this situation there is only one button required if there is no JavaScript. If the client-side detection realises it needs the button is it not better for it to already be on the page rather than require another request to get it?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how you are hiding it, are you using a DOM ready or a window ready? Window ready waits for all images to download, which is generally far too long.

For accessibility, reasons, I'd hide it on DOM loaded. But to ensure it won't show up, you could put it in a noscript element

```
<noscript>
    <input type="submit" />
</noscript>
```

As for your last paragraph, nothing like that can happen in the absence of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Just write unobtrusive javascript: http://icant.co.uk/articles/seven-rules-of-unobtrusive-javascript/.

What you do is write your page as a normal page, but, then use the code at the bottom to start the javascript, and start editing the page to make it more interactive. The beauty of this is that if they have javascript turned off the page is normal, but, if they have it on, then you can gracefully add more features.

I am not a big fan of the  option as that may mean lots of extra code to be downloaded that isn't needed.

On this page look at comment 5 for a good solution to be able to make changes before anything is actually displayed:
http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/06/again/

Answer (score 0):

You could use script before and after the submit button to write hidden div element start and end tags.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to start with your button shown, and then modify its CSS from JavaScript:

```
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
    <script>
        document.styleSheets[0].addRule(".hideMe", "display:none");
    </script>
    ...
</head>
```

Modifying the stylesheet instead of the button (and putting this code *outside* of an onload) ensures that it'll be hidden before the button is drawn.